# Как избавить от "жадности" оператор или?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, логирование

Всем привет! 
Задача следующая:
Есть лог файл содержащий сведения о сессиях:

```
13:00:00 Старт сессии
Сессия 1
14:00:00 Стоп сессии
бла бла бла
15:00:00 Старт сессии
Сессия 2
16:00:00 Стоп сессии
бла бла бла
```

Нужно выделить все сессии из лог файла, причем последняя сессия может быть не закрыта.
Пишу регулярку для выделения всех сессий:

```
[0..2][0..9]:[0..5][0..9]:[0..5][0..9] Старт сессии\r\n
(.*?)
(([0..2][0..9]:[0..5][0..9]:[0..5][0..9] Стоп сессии)|$)
```

В результате получаю сессии:

```
1) Сессия 1

2) Сессия 2
16:00:00 Стоп сессии
бла бла бла
```

Т.е. оператор "|" (или) выбирает самый длинный результат (игнорирует "Стоп сессии").
Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить данную регулярку.

Код такой:

```
string log = "....."
string pattern = @"[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] Старт сессии\r\n(?<Session>.*?)(([0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] Стоп сессии)|$)"; 
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(log);
...
```

Comment: Немного поподробнее. Что Вы пишите регулярку -- я понял. А вот с самой регулякой -- не понял. Немного кода не разорят отца русской демократии?

Comment: Дополнил фрагментом кода на C#

Comment: Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

Ну я не знаю, что здесь сказать

Comment: Что не так?

Comment: @grail333, что я опять все перепутал, все в порядке с этим. Я бы попробовал что-нибудь вроде

    "[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] Старт сессии\r\n(?:(?<Session>.*?$)([0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] Стоп сессии))?$"

Comment: Уважаемый @Fike, к сожалению ваше решение не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел неожиданное (для меня) решение: если в конце лог файла добавить перенос строки, то регулярное выражение срабатывает как надо.